# How to perform drag and drop in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to perform drag and drop in angular js.
This is my html in which i get the list of names that sholud be dragable

```
<li ng-repeat ="val1 in vm.settingsObj.application_status" ng-click="vm.addDefsingleAppStatus(val1)" ng-class="{'active':$index == 0}">
   <a data-toggle="pill"   ng-bind="val1.value" draggable="true"></a>
</li>
```

I am not sure about js code,can anyone help please.Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like: https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop ?

Comment: Hi victorlopezsanchez,actualy this is my perfect solution but i am not sure how to include it after npm install,https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Comment: can you -please suggest.

Comment: include:
**angular.module('myApp', ['dndLists'])**
and **<script src="../angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>**. Make sure it's in the _package.json_ the name: **angular-drag-and-drop-lists**